# Finding stable, unstable and centre manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Find the stable, unstable, and center manifolds of the following system
> \begin{align}
> \dot{x}& = -x,\\
>  \dot{y}& = -2y + 2z^2(1-z^2), \\
>  \dot{z} &= -z^3
> \end{align}
> at the origin. Prove that origin is the local attractor.

Solving the above system I got: $$x = x_0 \ e^{-t}, \ y(t) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{1}{t+z_0} + \bigg(\frac{2y_0  z_0 -1}{z_0}\bigg)e^{-2t} \bigg], \ z(t) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(t+z_0)}}$$

Stable manifold: $$W^{s}(0,0,0) := \{(x,y,z):x(t), y(t) \text{ and } z(t) \to 0 \text{ as } t \to +\infty\} =\{(x,0,z)\}$$

Unstable manifold: $$W^{u}(0,0,0) := \{(x,y,z):x(t), y(t) \text{ and } z(t) \to 0 \text{ as } t \to -\infty\} = \{(x,y,z):
x=0, yz=\frac{1}{2} \} $$

I do not whether my calculations are right or not. I do not know how to prove the second part.

Comment: The manifolds $W^s/W^u$ with exponential convergence rates are tangent to $E^s/E^u$. Find $E^s$ and $E^u$. Show that one of the $W^s/W^u$ doesn't exist and the other one coincides with the corresponding eigenspace (so your $W^s$ and $W^u$ are incorrect). We can find a center manifold (CM) by starting with a series approximation (we can also find the exact solution and observe that a CM is not unique but an analytic system can't have more than one analytic CM). But since the CM theorem applies, we only need to analyze the stability of $\dot z = -z^3$, without finding a CM at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the third equation has the solution
$$
z(t)^{-2}-z_0^{-2}=2t\implies z(t)=\frac{z_0}{\sqrt{1+2z_0^2t}}
$$
where now indeed $z(0)=z_0$.

Next, you can be a little creative in solving the second equation by inserting the third to reduce the 4th degree term,
$$
\dot y+2y=2z^2-2z^4=2z^2+2z\dot z=\frac{d}{dt}(z^2)+2z^2.
$$
This means that "luckily" the terms turn out to be that the same differential operator $(D+2)$ is applied to both sides. The solution then is
$$
y(t)-z(t)^2=(y_0-z_0^2)e^{-2t},\\
y(t)=\frac{z_0^2}{1+2z_0^2t}+(y_0-z_0^2)e^{-2t}.
$$
I do not see how there can be any unstable manifold. From points outside the set with $x_0=0$ and $y_0=z_0^2$ the solutions will converge exponentially fast towards points within that set, and then slowly along that set towards the origin. In my mind this was the characteristic of a center manifold?

Comment: For unstable manifolds, we need to check under what assumptions $x(t), y(t), \text{ and } z(t) \to 0 \text{ as } t \to - \infty $. From your solution, Can I say that $(0,z^2,z)$ is an unstable manifold? @Lutz

Comment: For stable manifold: I was thinking if I start at $y =0, z=0$. I will be left with $$\dot{x} = -x$$ whose solution converges to zero.